# Angular useValue and injection token

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In my angular app I have

```
{ provide: QUEUE, useValue: window.events }
```

in my providers. I was wondering how can I set QUEUE to use an empty array [] if window.events are undefined. I tried something like this and it didn't work.

```
  { provide: QUEUE, useValue: window.events || [] }
```

Here is what I have in `QUEUE.injection-token.ts`

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const \QUEUE = new InjectionToken<Array<AppEvent>>('QUEUE');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please, update the question with what *it didn't work* means. If there's error message, cite it. This will help other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.events || []` check should be performed at runtime because [`window` doesn't exist at compilation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445947/window-is-undefined-when-used-as-usevalue-provider-with-angular-4-aot).

It likely should be:

```
export function queueFactory(): any[] {
    return window.events || [];
}

...
providers: [ provide: QUEUE, useFactory: queueFactory }]
...
```